# With spring boot, how does it detect a JTA environment?

Tags: spring-boot, jta, spring-jms, atomikos

I'm trying to enable JTA with spring boot so that JPA and JMS will roll back together.  All docs point to http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-jta.html and it states

> When a JTA environment is detected, Spring’s JtaTransactionManager
>   will be used to manage transactions.

What is meant by "JTA environment is detected"?

I ask because I think that is what is tripping me up.  I added dependencies for Atomikos<del>, but `jmsTemplate.isSessionTransacted()` returns `false`</del>.  I am assuming I haven't properly marked my environment as JTA.  I'm running with embedded tomcat.

What I am experiencing is the database changes are being rolledback with the transaction, but not the JMS messages.

**UPDATE:**

The part about `sessionTransacted` was not related.  It was my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JTA environment is detected when a supported transaction manager is on the classpath (Atomikos or Bitronix in 1.3, and also Narayana in 1.4) or because a `javax.transaction.TransactionManager` is available in JNDI (typically because you've deployed your Boot app to a Java EE container).

I think you have misunderstood the purpose of the `sessionTransacted` flag on `JmsTemplate`. It's used when creating a new session (`Connection.createSession`), however the `transacted` value that's passed to `createSession` is ignored when you're running in a JTA environment.

Comment: A co-worker pointed out what yous said about `sessionTransacted`, so I guess that was a red herring.  The JMS message is being sent when the transaction rolls back.

Answer (score 1):

You can see it in the class `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.JtaAutoConfiguration`:

```
@ConditionalOnClass(javax.transaction.Transaction.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.jta", value = "enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
@AutoConfigureBefore({ XADataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        ActiveMQAutoConfiguration.class, HornetQAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
@Import({ JndiJtaConfiguration.class, BitronixJtaConfiguration.class,
        AtomikosJtaConfiguration.class, NarayanaJtaConfiguration.class })
@EnableConfigurationProperties(JtaProperties.class)
public class JtaAutoConfiguration {

}
```

Basically you have to have the JTA API on the classpath, and at least one JTA provider (Bitronix or Atomikos, if you're not using an application server).